# Using underscore to sort nested objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, underscore.js

Consider the following expanded object:

[image]

Now each of these objects is stored into an array and its easy to sort by name, email, created_at or what ever else. But what about if I wanted to sore by the users profile investor type. In the image you would do: `data.profile.data.investor_type` to get the investor type.

How do I use underscore to sort an array of these objects by nested attributes in the object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting nested objects using Javascript and/or Underscore.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810286/sorting-nested-objects-using-javascript-and-or-underscore-js)

Comment: no its not a duplicate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`_.sortBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) with the exact code you have show

```
_.sortBy(data, function(obj) { return obj.profile.data.investor_type; });
```

If your environment supports [ECMA Script 2015's Fat-arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), then you can write the same as

```
_.sortBy(data, (obj) => obj.profile.data.investor_type);
```

Comment: I am a bit lost how will this sort the array of objects by the investor type in this case?

Comment: For every element in the array, corresponding `investor_type` is used for comparisons. So, the array of objects will be sorted based on the `investor_type`.

Comment: you definitely have to read the _.sortBy function as sort the array by the given value I specify, in your case "profile.data.investor_type". a fiddle entry to play : https://jsfiddle.net/zobidafly/g45pereL/

Comment: @zobidafly Do you mean to say this solution will not work?

Comment: @thefourtheye : no, it works, I just added a comment and a link to check that it works...